# Discord.py eval error spitting out random junk

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've created a working eval command. Just when I use it, it also spits out this:

[image: command response]

This is currently my code:

```
@commands.is_owner()
@client.command(name='eval')
async def eval_(ctx, *, command):
    res2 = eval(command)
    if inspect.isawaitable(res2):
        embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Eval', description='' , colour=discord.Colour.green())

        embed.add_field(name='Input', value=f'||{await res2}||', inline=False)


        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2):

That's just the [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of a Message object.
You didn't provide the input that resulted in that output, but assuming `res2` is a coroutine that returns a Message object, you're formatting the result to a string, so it's outputting the string representation of the Message object, as expected.